# Implementing Bates distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, optimization, python

I've been trying to plot the Bates distribution curve, The Bates distribution is the distribution of the mean of n independent standard uniform variates (from 0 to 1).

(I worked on the interval [-1;1], I made a simple change of variable).

The curve destabilizes after such number of n, which prevents me from moving forward. In order to consider that the variable x is continuous, I sampled interval in 10**6 samples. Here are some examples for different n:
[distributions of some differents n](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpfnX.png)

But for n greater than 29, the curve diverges, and the greater n, the closer the deformation caused by the divergence is to the (mean) center of the curve:
[divergence of the distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyBWN.png)

The Bates distribution of probability is defined as follows:
[equqtion of Bate distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2VHB.png)

My code:

```
samples=10**6

def combinaison(n,k):   # combination of K out of N
  cnk=fac(n)/(fac(k)*fac(abs(n-k))) # fac is factoriel 
  return cnk


def dens_probas(a,b,n):
  x=np.linspace(a, b, num=samples)
  y=(x-a)/(b-a)
  F=list()
  for i in range(0,len(y)):
    g=0
    for k in range(0,int(n*y[i]+1)):
      g=g+pow(-1,k)*combinaison(n,k)*pow(y[i]-k/n,n-1)
    d=(n**n/fac(n-1))*g
    F.append(d)         
  return F
```

Any idea to correct the divergence for larger n

Thank you

Comment: That looks like rounding errors.  One step which will get you a little way forward is to use the symmetry of the distribution so making the right tail match the left tail where there is less of a problem.  But if $n$ is large enough the question is why do this at all: you will have something very close to a normal distribution

Comment: First, look at [Irwin-Hall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution) Distribution, which is for the _sum_ of standard uniform distributions. Mean converges to normal quickly with almost normal results for $n$ as small as 10.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simulation (in R) of the distribution of the average `a` of 10 independent standard uniform random variables (based on a million averages of ten simulated standard uniforms).

```
set.seed(2020)
a = replicate(10^6, mean(runif(10)))
summary(a); sd(a)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.1142  0.4377  0.5002  0.5001  0.5626  0.8917 
[1] 0.09139322

hist(a, prob=T, br=30, ylim=c(0,5), col="skyblue2")
  curve(dnorm(x, mean(a), sd(a)), add=T, lwd=2, col="red")
```

[image]

The red curve is for the normal density with mean matching the mean $(\approx 0.5)$ of a million
averages of ten and SD matching the SD $(\approx 0.091)$ of the million averages.

The first 1000 averages pass a Shapiro-Wilk normality test.

```
shapiro.test(a[1:1000])

        Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  a[1:1000]
W = 0.99761, p-value = 0.1541
```

However, S-W tests for larger numbers of values from `a` may
fail any normality test because the match to normal is not
quite perfect for averages of ten standard uniforms. Of course,
the support of the distribution of $\bar X_{10}$'s will be
$(0,1)$ [about $\pm 5\sigma],$ not $(-\infty,\infty).$

*Note:* Ever since digital computers became available, there has been a demand for variates that are "indistinguishable in practice" from normal samples. In the early days of computation (1950's and 60's), when
computing beyond basic arithmetic was expensive, it was common
to use $Z = \sum_{i=1}^{12} U_i - 6,$ where $U_i \stackrel{iid}{\sim}
\mathsf{Unif}(0,1),$ to simulate $Z \stackrel {aprx}{\sim} \mathsf{Norm}(0,1).$ [Support $(-6, 6).]$ Next was to use the Box-Muller transformation (two uniforms to get two normals via log and trig functions, see Wikipedia). [Because of overflow/underflow with transindental functions, essentially limited to $(-7,7).]$ Nowadays, many
statistical software programs (including R) use Michael Wichura's rational approximation to the normal quantile function, which is accurate within
the limits of double precision computation.

Comment: I suspect Anas Bakkali may be aware of the normal approximation.  But I think the question here is about implementing an exact expression for the density

Comment: @Henry: Hard to tell how to be most helpful here, other than trying to correct the unexplained, undocumented code, which I have seldom found fruitful. Perhaps first, there are serious misconceptions that need to be addressed. Such as "But for n greater than 29, the curve diverges, and the greater n, the closer the deformation caused by the divergence is to the (mean) center of the curve." And a look at links along with my simulation shows what really happens. Some help with "Any idea to correct the divergence for larger n." Shows no inkling of awareness of normal aprx.